# C++: redefining public class methods from imported shared library?

Tags: c++, dll, linker

Suppose I have a shared library with a class that defines public non-virtual methods, and I want to import said shared library but re-defining some of those class methods **without creating a new class**, in a way that the library would call the methods I redefine when those are used internally within the shared library.

From some experiments with GCC in linux, everything seems to work as intended, but I am wondering if I am just getting lucky or if what I am doing is guaranteed to work correctly in other environments.

Example:

- `shared.h`:

```cpp
class Myclass {
public:
    int val;
    void set_myval(); //I want to override this
    void set_myval_v2();
    void print_myval();
};
```

- `shared.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "shared.h"

void Myclass::set_myval() {
    this->val = 100;
}
void Myclass::set_myval_v2() {
    this->set_myval();
}
void Myclass::print_myval() {
    std::cout << "val:" << this->val << std::endl;
}
```

- `app.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "shared.h"

void Myclass::set_myval() {
    this->val = 200;
}

int main()
{
    Myclass obj;
    obj.set_myval();
    obj.print_myval();

    obj.set_myval_v2();
    obj.print_myval();
    return 0;
}
```

I then compile it and run as follows:

```
g++ -c -fPIC shared.cpp -o shared.o
gcc shared.o -shared -o libshared.so
g++ app.cpp -L<path> -l:libshared.so -Wl,-rpath=<path>
./a.out
```

```
val:200
val:200
```

Is this guaranteed to work when done in other compilers/OSes/etc.?

Comment: Your approach may work with a particular platform (OS, loader, compiler, linker), but it is not portable, and there are no guarantees that the approach will work in other environments.

Comment: Try building with optimizations enabled; chances are high `set_myval` call in `set_myval_v2` will get inlined. Your program contains a One Definition Rule (ODR) violation, and is therefore ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That is what the C++ language has to say about the program. But since shared libraries are involved, that is not the last word. The platform specifies additional behavior of shared libraries. Still, the outcome is basically luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is a violation of C++ ODR rule and is handled in different ways on different platforms. It is not portable even for GCC - interposition will not work if e.g. the symbols in code have protected visibility or library has been linked with `-Wl,-Bsymbolic` or with `-fno-semantic-interposition`.